# Microsoft Graph InTune Beta API's

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I'm trying to test some of the beta InTune specific Graph API's but they require either of the following scopes:
DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All; DeviceManagementApps.Read.All

When I create a test app, I don't see either of those as app or delegation permissions.

I have tried creating a test app in both the Azure AD and Azure AD 2.0 endpoint.  I can see that the beta API exists by querying https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata but when I try using any of them I get the following response:

Status Code: 401

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: 054070f2-43ab-4ea2-8150-b91449faaadd - Url: https://fef.amsua0502.manage.microsoft.com/MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/managedAppStatuses?api-version=2016-06-16",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "054070f2-43ab-4ea2-8150-b91449faaadd",
            "date": "2017-01-12T19:24:03"
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the Microsoft Intune team, specifically on the integration between Microsoft Intune and Microsoft Graph.

Currently the scopes are not available in the Azure AD endpoints, but we are working to resolve that by the end of the month, since the scopes are not yet available we are not enforcing that they are assigned to your app. Once the scopes are available in the Azure AD endpoints we will enforce that they are assigned to your app.

The reason that you are getting the error is that you do not have an Intune license assigned to the account you are using to call into Microsoft Graph. This is a limitation of the current preview, that we are hoping to remove sometime soon. In the meantime you should be able to work around this problem by assigning an Intune license using the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/get-started/start-with-a-paid-subscription-to-microsoft-intune-step-4

You should also note that currently the Intune APIs are only available to users who have access to the Microsoft Intune in the Azure portal preview. You can see more information on the Microsoft Intune in the Azure portal preview at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-azure/introduction/what-is-microsoft-intune

Hope this helps

Peter

Comment: Just wanted to let you now that the scopes for Microsoft Intune are now available in Azure AD, and are documented on https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following article: [Active Directory V2 Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-scopes)

This might also help: [Authentication Overview (MS GRAPH)](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview)

Note that your application must request permissions to the APIs that you want to access. You can set the permissions you want to request statically by configuring your application to have "Required Resource Access" to the APIs you want. Or the better option would be to dynamically request for the permissions you need as you are requesting the access token. Instructions on how to do that are in the first link above.

You can verify that your token has the correct scopes by decoding the token and checking the "scp" claim in the token, which should contain a space separated list of scopes that your app has been granted access for.

It seems to me that you have registered an app correctly, but have not quite implemented the correct settings or processes needed to get the scopes you want.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the references.  I went through them initially.  I also tested against my tenant using Graph Explorer and run in to the same issue even when it tries to get the additional permissions so I just dont think that my tenant is enabled for these particular scopes.  Also if you look at all the scopes here - https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes, Device Management isn't even listed under the preview section.

Comment: How did you hear about these new scopes?

Comment: If you look at any of the InTune Graph API's you will see at the top that DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All or DeviceManagementApps.Read.All are required scopes.  Here's a link to one of the APIs - https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_androidmanagedappprotection_create

Comment: Sorry - we've not updated the permissions topic yet to include the Intune permissions.  We'll get around to that soon. Someone from the Intune team should help answer this soon.